# PHP Regex batch update

Tags: php

In short, I want to talk about my problem;

```
$text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.';
$text = preg_replace('#(?<!((alt|src)="))Lorem(?!(.*("|<\/a>)))#i', '<a href="Lorem" title="Lorem" style="color: inherit;">\0</a>', $text);
$text = preg_replace('#(?<!((alt|src)="))Ipsum(?!(.*("|<\/a>)))#i', '<a href="Ipsum" title="Ipsum" style="color: inherit;">\0</a>', $text);
echo $text;
```

"**Lorem**" changes, but "**Ipsum**" does not change.

The result of php above:

```html
<a href="Lorem" title="Lorem" style="color: inherit;">Lorem</a> Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <a href="Lorem" title="Lorem" style="color: inherit;">Lorem</a> Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing <a href="Lorem" title="Lorem" style="color: inherit;">Lorem</a> Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of <a href="Lorem" title="Lorem" style="color: inherit;">Lorem</a> <a href="Ipsum" title="Ipsum" style="color: inherit;">Ipsum</a>.
```

Why doesn't "**Ipsum**" change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### **Edited:**

If you comment out the first `preg_replace` line the -*used to be*- second `preg_replace` will work just fine. [**PHP Fiddle 1**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/dd2x-rskw) <sup>hit F9 to run</sup>

Also if you swap the the places of the two `preg_replace`'s you'll get "**Ipsum**" replaced but not "**Lorem**" [**PHP Fiddle 2**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/w2ng-ctps)

So, *if the two words are not initially in anchor tags* **`<a>`**, you don't need to have the lookbehind and lookahead conditions, or at least, not in the second **`preg_replace`**, otherwise the two lookaround conditions will be true
[**PHP Fiddle 3**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/cf8z-xfri) <sup>(**1**)</sup>

---

#### **Update:**

As mentioned in a comment by the OP, when using the above there will be a problem if string **`$text`** has **`<a>`** tags with same criteria words, something like :

```
 <a href="">test Lorem test</a>
```

In this case, using REGEX alone won't do it IMHO, Instead we need to do the following:

1. Check for any occurrence of anchor tags **`<a>`** in the string **`$text`**.
2. Use an array **`$tempArr`**, as a temporary storage to store link elements.
3. Replace every link element with some text that has a different form, with number as an unique ID, final result: **`tempRep#0`**, **`tempRep#1`** .. etc, one for and in place of every link element.
4. Run the REGEX statement(s) <sup>(**2**)</sup>.
5. Now we reverse the process in step #3, we replace  **`tempRep#0`**, **`tempRep#1`** .. etc, with their corresponding link elements which we have temporarily stored as array elements in the **`$tempArr`**, matching the number in each unique ID with the same array index number <sup>(**3**)</sup>.

The above algorithm could be achieved with JavaScript because we need some Document Object Model checking, but as the OP said, Javascript is not an option, so we need to make use of the [**`PHP Document Object Model`**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) by loading the string **`$text`** as HTML, and make use of these PHP DOM commands: **`getElementsByTagName()`** , **`getAttribute()`** and **`textContent`** ( or alternatively, **`nodeValue`**).

So finally, we have the following:

[**PHP Fiddle 4**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/iznp-4yia) [ Final ]

```php
$text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of <a href="link1href" title="test1">test Ipsum Lorem test</a> Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of <a href="link2href" title="test2">test Lorem test</a> Lorem Ipsum.';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($text);
$tempArr = array();
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link) {  
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    $title = $link->getAttribute('title');
    $textCont = $link->textContent; //Alternatively, $link->->nodeValue could be used too
    $linkElement = '<a href="' . $href . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $textCont . '</a>';
    $tempArr[] = $linkElement;
}

for($i=0; $i < count($tempArr); $i++){
    $text = str_replace($tempArr[$i], 'tempRep#' . $i, $text);
}

$text = preg_replace('#(?<!(alt|src)=")(Lorem|Ipsum)(?!(("|<\/a>)))#i', '<a href="\0" title="\0" style="color: inherit;">\0</a>', $text);

for($i=0; $i < count($tempArr); $i++){
    $text = str_replace('tempRep#' . $i, $tempArr[$i], $text);
}
echo $text;
```

### -----------------------------

**Notes:**

1. I have found out that it's only the *lookahead* condition in the second `preg_replace` function is what causing the bug, in this
   [**PHP Fiddle 5**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/9378-gtk6), I kept the lookbehind and only removed the lookahead and oddly it is still working fine.
2. I've merged the 2 REGEX statements into one:

   ```
   $text = preg_replace('#(?<!(alt|src)=")(Lorem|Ipsum)(?!(("|<\/a>)))#i', '<a href="\0" title="\0" style="color: inherit;">\0</a>', $text);
   ```
3. this why we used a unique ID for each replacement.

Comment: I do not want to touch the words in the html tags, like the annoyance with the method you specify. What do I do when I want to change 10 words? Regex de (?! (. * ("| <\ / A>))) we can edit this?

Comment: I guess so, if you remove the **`.*`** and you'll end with **`(?!(("|<\/a>)))`** instead it will work too.. [**PHP Fiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/fc2w-4hgu).. check it and see if it works for you

Comment: Your reply has made a lot of sense, thank you very much :)

Comment: There is something wrong with entering the word clan. Example: <a href="">test Lorem test</a>

Comment: The last case "`<a href="">test Lorem test</a>`" is too hard to achieve using regex only,, do you have the luxury to use JavaScript instead of PHP? because you'll need to do some Node checking.s then I've already solved it using Javascript

Comment: @user3342378 All have been fixed now using PHP, check the updated part in my answer